# Firebase sort query gives (unsorted) dictionary results

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm sure I'm missing something here, but when I wish to do a query for, say, the top 10 scores in a certain game, Firebase returns the top 10 scores, however since they are then gives back as a dictionary (key generated with childByAutoId), they are 'unsorted' when received on the client side (so to display a top 10 you have to sort them again)...

```
FIRDatabaseReference *ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
FIRDatabaseQuery *jungleHighscoresQuery = [[[ref child:@"jungleScores"] queryOrderedByChild:@"score"] queryLimitedToLast:4];
[jungleHighscoresQuery observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot){
    NSDictionary *postDict = snapshot.value;


    NSLog(@"%@", postDict);
}];
```

The above code gives the following output (these are the top 4 scores among the ~20 in the database):

```
    {
    "-KIUhe_9TLQoy_zNbJT0" =     {
        score = 290;
        userid = oMqoPGJYsGWHffYx8N6vDk3Osh72;
    };
    "-KIUj8VUyNMgyZ135dI_" =     {
        score = 560;
        userid = oMqoPGJYsGWHffYx8N6vDk3Osh72;
    };
    "-KIUjK15Gy9PRB_JBWOA" =     {
        score = 240;
        userid = oMqoPGJYsGWHffYx8N6vDk3Osh72;
    };
    "-KIUlZ1a03r7bjPYNueG" =     {
        score = 740;
        userid = oMqoPGJYsGWHffYx8N6vDk3Osh72;
    };
}
```

I know it's an easy task to just sort it all again, but it seems weird to have to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an easy solution after all, just had to grab the enumerator instead of the dictionary:

```
 NSEnumerator *enumerator = snapshot.children;
```

and then just iterate through them with `[enumerator nextObject]`